# Class Initialization in Form load with delegate

Tags: c#, forms, delegates, initialization

I want only to initialize the class Test in Form1()!
If i start the program with the code below the constructor Test in Class Test is called.

Test in Class test is a funcion which reflects back to form1 callbackFunction.
But I want to call it in Timer1_Tick not on Form/Program start!

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Form 1 Code:

```
namespace Klasse
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
        private Button[] button;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int getroffen = 0;

        public Form1()
        {

            Test Object = new Test(rand,callbackFunction);

            InitializeComponent();
            button = new Button[5];
            timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Interval = rand.Next(500, 1001);
            timer1.Start();         
            button[0] = button1;
            button[1] = button2;
            button[2] = button3;
            button[3] = button4;
            button[4] = button5;
        }

        void Timer1_Tick(object sender,EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();   
        }

        void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           getroffen = Convert.ToInt16(((Button)sender).Name);    
        }

        void callbackFunction(int buttonNr, bool aktiv)
        {
            if (aktiv == true)
            {
                button[buttonNr-1].BackColor = Color.Red;

            }
            if (aktiv == false)
            {
                button[buttonNr-1].BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
            }
            timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Interval = rand.Next(500, 1001);
            timer1.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Class Code:

```
namespace Klasse
{


    class Test

    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Der Haupteinstiegspunkt für die Anwendung.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());

        }

        public delegate void ButtonAktivieren(int button ,bool passiv);

        private int anzahlGezeigt = 0;

        private int anzahlTreffer = 0;

        private int button = 0;

        private bool passiv;
        public bool Passiv
        {
            get { return passiv; }
        }

        private Random zufall;

        private ButtonAktivieren aktivierenCallback;

        public Test (Random zufall, ButtonAktivieren aktivierenCallback)
        {
            anzahlGezeigt++;
            if (anzahlGezeigt % 2 == 0)
            {
                aktivierenCallback(button, passiv);
            }
            if (anzahlGezeigt %2 > 0)
            {
            button = zufall.Next(1, 6);
            aktivierenCallback(button, passiv);    
            }

        }

        public void Aktivieren()
        {
            passiv = true;
        }

        public void Passivieren()
        {
            passiv = false;
        }

        private void CheckGameOver()
        {
            if (anzahlGezeigt > anzahlTreffer)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Game Over!");
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        public void Getroffen(int getroffenerButton)
        {
            if (getroffenerButton == button)
            {
                anzahlTreffer++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you want to start the timer? You can put the timer1.Start();  in his own method.

Comment: The timer should start on form load and the Timer1_Tick should call the callbackFunction...

Comment: Just have the Tick event handler call the method.  You'll need to focus a bit on exactly *what* button you are going to let the timer activate.  It isn't clear from the question but it would be typical to make it the "last button clicked".  So you'll need another variable that stores what button was last clicked so the timer can click it again.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `Test` method callable, not a constructor, like `StartTest` below.

```
    public void StartTest (Random zufall, ButtonAktivieren aktivierenCallback)
    {
        anzahlGezeigt++;
        if (anzahlGezeigt % 2 == 0)
        {
            aktivierenCallback(button, passiv);
        }
        if (anzahlGezeigt %2 > 0)
        {
        button = zufall.Next(1, 6);
        aktivierenCallback(button, passiv);    
        }

    }

    public void Aktivieren(Random zufall, ButtonAktivieren aktivierenCallback)

    {
        passiv = true;
        StartTest(Random zufall, ButtonAktivieren aktivierenCallback);
    }
```

---

Form code adjusts:

```
    Test Object;

    public Form1()
    {
        //some initializing code

        Object = new Test();

        //the rest of initializing code
    }




    void Timer1_Tick(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        Object.StartTest(rand, callbackFunction)
        timer1.Stop();   
    }
```

---

Or another way: store the `Random zufall` and the `ButtonAktivieren aktivierenCallback` in the `test class` in constructor and use them in activation:

```
    Random _zufall;
    ButtonAktivieren _aktivierenCallback;


    public void Test (Random zufall, ButtonAktivieren aktivierenCallback)
    {
        _zufall = zufall;
        _aktivierenCallback = aktivierenCallback;
    }


    public void Aktivieren()
    {
        passiv = true;

        anzahlGezeigt++;
        if (anzahlGezeigt % 2 == 0)
        {
            _aktivierenCallback(button, passiv);
        }
        if (anzahlGezeigt %2 > 0)
        {
        button = _zufall.Next(1, 6);
        _aktivierenCallback(button, passiv);    
        }
    }
```